Has any western nation spoken against the persecution of the Hindu minority in Bangladesh?
As part of the so-called student protests/anti-dictatorship protests and accompanying violence in Bangladesh, there were numerous attacks against people of the Hindu minority.
This has been reported by some western newspapers. For example, the New York Times: Hindus in Bangladesh Face Revenge Attacks After Prime Minister’s Exit. The western newspapers' coverage of this violence is very low.
Has any western nation (that is, leaders representing official government positions) spoken specifically against the persecution of the Hindu minority in Bangladesh in connection with this unrest?

probably none.  There seems to be an expectation that when "some group I identify with" suffers persecution, that "western nations" have some duty to do something about it.  Why?  Have the leaders of South Asian countries spoken against the rioters in the UK? Why not? Does this mean that Modi and Zadari secretly support the EDL?  Why doesn't Modi/Zadari care about this important issue?

@JamesK the western nations are very happy and willing to lecture other countries in general.

@whoisit It is a bit of a developing story though, innit?  Which government would said Western spokespersons lodge complaints with, at this point?  India seems like it would be well placed to express concerns, but it's not exactly in good graces wrt how Modi's been treating Muslims, well outside of exceptional circumstances.  I hope Bangladesh settles down for the better, the world has no great need for another Pakistan-style of grievance-based religious governance.  It's in the Western news for sure, but it seems premature to get too involved beyond calls for restraint and clean elections.

@JamesK: actually a few Indians were targeted, and some of the Indian press remarked that. E.g. https://www.indiatoday.in/world/uk-news/story/riots-uk-southport-killings-axel-rudakubana-muslim-anti-immigration-riots-counter-protests-thuggery-keir-starmer-pm-2577901-2024-08-07

@timetakesitstoll so why doens't Modi denounce them?  Why is Modi always backing thugs like this?

Edited to include only in response to the recent incident so it is sufficiently focused. Whether any Western country had taken a position about persecution of the Hindu minority there for all time is too broad.


persecution of the hindu minority in Bangladesh [...] especially recently?

This would have to be perceived as such, i.e. on ethnic or religious grounds. And whether it's true or not, I think largely it's been considered a 'purely political' conflict in the West, largely ignoring any ethnic divisions between the parties. See e.g. this VOA coverage when the elections were boycotted by the opposition. And to be fair, the opposition itself didn't speak of being oppressed on ethnic or religius grounds, e.g.:

Saying that “democracy is dead” in Bangladesh, Abdul Moyeen Khan, a member of the Bangladesh Nationalist Party, the country’s largest opposition party, said that under Prime Minister Sheikh Hasina’s Awami League government, there cannot be “any free and fair election.”
“The Awami League government has completely monopolized the civil administration, police administration, the judiciary as well as all the independent public institutions in the country, including the election commission. There is no way to ensure free, fair and neutral elections in Bangladesh under the present setup,” Khan told VOA on Thursday.

OTOH the Hindu minority might have been better off with Awami League in power, as perusing the Wikipedia article on the BNP we can find a nugget like (this quote from the Indian press):

When right-wing Bangladesh Nationalist Party (BNP) and its Islamist ally, Jamaat-e-Islami, won the general election in 2001, the minority Hindus bore the brunt of the celebration.

But with the general violence in Bangladesh recently, I'm sure any events targeted at Hindus were easy to miss by high-level politicians, even if some of the Western press didn't miss that: 'There is no law and order. And Hindus are being targeted again'.

Mr Sarkar told me that he was shocked, but not entirely surprised by the incident. Hindu minorities in Bangladesh, he says, are largely viewed as supporters of Sheikh Hasina’s secular Awami League party and are often attacked by rivals in a country where Islam is the state religion.
After Ms Hasina fled the country, social media was flooded with reports of Hindu properties and temples being attacked. India's Foreign Minister S Jaishankar told parliament on Tuesday: "What was particularly worrying was that minorities, their businesses and temples also came under attack at multiple locations. The full extent of this is still not clear."

FWTW, "Indian-American congressmen call for immediate end to violence against Hindus in Bangladesh".

They also said the failure of Congress and the administration to acknowledge and condemn the violence against Hindus and other religious minorities is unacceptable.


N.B. those two (Khanna & Krishnamoorthi --- being quoted in the last piece) happen to be all the Hindu members of US Congress presently https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hindu_members_of_the_United_States_Congress

We could add Tommy Robinson, although his main concern might be something else. https://www.bbc.com/news/articles/cx2n8pzk7gzo

The Guardian voices the issue openly as of Aug 10:
https://www.theguardian.com/world/article/2024/aug/10/bangladeshis-pm-flees-protesters-sheikh-hasina-muhammad-yunus

But most concerning for many have been attacks on the Hindu minority.
Rana Dasgupta, who leads a group representing minorities, the
Bangladesh Hindu Buddhist Christian Unity Council, said Islamist
groups seemed to be taking advantage of the chaos to make Hindus feel
unsafe.

